# Manejo de ObjectContext goblal para EF para una Web Application en .NET

Tags: c#, entity-framework

¿Como emular un `Unit of Work` usando EF4 para un proyecto web y tener un único `ObjectContext` para poder acceder al mismo de manera global en la aplicación?

Answer (score 1):

Para implementar `UoW` tambien requiere implementar el patron `Repository`, de esta forma poder desacoplar las accion del controller o tu capa de negocio de la persistencia.

[Implementing the Repository and Unit of Work Patterns in an ASP.NET MVC Application (9 of 10)](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

Lo que no mencionas es si estas usndo EF `Code First` o lo implementas mediante un `edmx`, recomiendo usar `Code First`, es lo mejor.

Una aclaracion, que sea global no quiere decir que la instancia sea la misma cada vez que vas al servidor, sino que esta la debes realizar por Request, por cada invocacion del browser sera una instancia nueva del context de EF

Por otro lado evaluaste usar alguna libreria de IoC para poder inyectar la instancia del contexto en el constructor donde la necesites.

Answer (score 1):

1. No *emulas*, si no **encapsulas** EF con *UnitOfWork*. Se hace esto por una simple razón, ya que EF en si implementa los 2 patrones: Poder tener capa de persistencia de de datos en un ensamblado que dependa de todas las dependencias de EF antes que todos los ensamblados que usen la capa de datos dependen de las dependencias de EF.
2. Hay 2 aproximaciones para que sea global el EF:

   1. Implementando **IHttpModule** y poner un *singleton* de EF en la implementación. Esto te hara tener un solo EF para todos los clientes y todas las llamadas. Cuidado con esto a la hora de tener concurrencia.
   2. Registrando en **HttpApplication** el EF para que solo dure durante el ciclo de vida de la correspondiente a la aplicacion.

Si quieres mas información al respecto, puede consultar la entrada siguiente pagina: [Managing DbContext the right way with Entity Framework 6: an in-depth guide](http://mehdi.me/ambient-dbcontext-in-ef6/). Abarca, de manera muy extensa y profunda, tu problematica.